# Why does moving a value generate LLVM IR that includes a value copy?

Tags: rust, move

If I assign a variable (with a type without copy semantics) to a second one, rustc creates a copy of the value even if the first one cannot be used/accessed anymore.

For example:

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
struct T {
    val: i32,
}
fn main() {
    let v1 = T { val: 123 };
    let v2 = v1;
    // println!("{:?}", v1); error!
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}
```

This generates LLVM IR which contains two store operations:

```
  %v2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %v1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 123, i32* %v1, align 4
  store i32 123, i32* %v2, align 4
```

Isn't it unnecessary workload to copy values with move semantics if the first copy cannot be used anymore?

Answer (score 2):

LLVM was specifically designed to perform optimizations. A front-end will try to encode everything it knows about the operations being performed in the LLVM IR and then invoke optimizations upon the LLVM IR.

If you turn on optimizations you'll indeed only get:

```
  %v2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %0 = bitcast i32* %v2 to i8*, !dbg !36
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %0), !dbg !36
  store i32 123, i32* %v2, align 4, !dbg !37
```

`%v1` has been optimized away entirely.

https://godbolt.org/z/fW9457eEn

Comment: But why should it make any sense to encode this in the first place?  The compiler knows that the first copy cannot be used anymore, cause it's forbidden by the semantics. So there is no reason to generate such instructions at all. Wouldn't that introduce unecessary copies if llvm fails to detect the "junk copies"?

Comment: @Sebi2020 why would the compiler choose to reimplement every optimization that LLVM has?

Comment: @Sebi2020 I was speaking generally. In this particular case it appears the rust compiler doesn't encode this piece of information. The reason for compilers working this way is generally reducing complexity by abstraction. Compilers are huge, complex pieces of software. Semantic analysis often occurs entirely independently from code generation. It wouldn't make any sense to implement this kind of logic again if LLVM can handle this already and only worsen maintainability. Writing compilers is often a trade-off between maintainability and optimizing every corner case.

Comment: @Shepmaster Nobody said that every optimization LLVM has should be implemented by the compiler. I'm just wondering why the compiler translates moves to copies. This is just something that makes no sense to me.

Comment: @idmean Yes, I see the point that it's a good idea to have a separation of concerns, but there are cases this separation fails. For example I've found threads on stackoverflow showing that llvm fails to do this sort of optimization with large arrays, but the compiler (the sem. analyzer part of it) knows that we just used a new alias for the same value (by moving it). I was just wondering, because the move semantic is such a basic language construct (it even has it's own keyword `move`) that it would make sense to make it a separate op, which could be reflected in the codegen stage, but isn't.

Comment: @Sebi2020 Yup, that can make sense. One additional reason why Rust doesn't do this is probably that it's very hard (to that point where it's just a bad idea) to extend LLVM IR with additional instructions. But Apple has taken an approach as you suggest where they first lower Swift to SIL (Swift Intermediate language), which is loosely based on LLVM IR but at slightly higher level, perform high level optimizations there and then lower SIL to LLVM IR. This is even more interesting considering that Chris Lattner himself was part of the team that designed this architecture.

Comment: @idmean I didn't mean that they should extend LLVM IR  with additional instructions, but instead if they see something like `let l2 = l1` emit no store instructions and just use l1 instead of l2 in LLVM IR if l2 appears in the source code (cause it's a move and the semantics imply the second copy does not fulfill any purpose (if l1 is not mutable)). I just don't see it as an optimiziation to convert copies to moves, but the approach of Apple sounds interesting, if the goal is to do a bunch of high level optimizations by the compiler itself.

Comment: continue:  But I understand that code generation and semantic checks can take place at different levels and have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Because copy vs move is **language semantics** not how it is done in the generated code. Rust always (maybe that have changed?) generates copy and then just logically disallows usage of the moved value. It relies on LLVM ability to remove unneeded copies.